# Escrenvendo no console Async

Tags: c#, multithreading

Como fazer um programa Console, enquanto ele processa algumas task ele executar uma escrita no console (tipo um contador) assíncrono? independente.

Ou seja ele ficará escrevendo independente dos outros processos.
Algo como:

ex:

```
        private static async Task EscreveConsole()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.CursorTop = 4;
                Console.CursorLeft = 90;
                Console.Write("/"); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.CursorTop = 4;
                Console.CursorLeft = 90;
                Console.Write("-"); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.CursorTop = 4;
                Console.CursorLeft = 90;
                Console.Write("\\"); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.CursorTop = 4;
                Console.CursorLeft = 90;
                Console.Write("|"); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.CursorTop = 4;
                Console.CursorLeft = 90;
                Console.Write("-"); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.CursorTop = 4;
                Console.CursorLeft = 90;
                Console.Write("|"); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.CursorTop = 4;
                Console.CursorLeft = 90;
                Console.Write("/");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EscreveConsole().ConfigureAwait(false);// queria q isso executasse independentemente

TarefaBaseAsync().Wait();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Objetivo era criar uma barra de progresso, consegui desenvolver algo como abaixo.

```
public class ProgressBar : IDisposable, IProgress<double>
    {
        public int blockCount = 20;

        private readonly TimeSpan animationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / 8);
        private const string animation = @"|/-\";

        private readonly Timer timer;

        private double currentProgress = 0;
        private string currentText = string.Empty;
        private bool disposed = false;
        private int animationIndex = 0;

        public ProgressBar()
        {

            if (!Console.IsOutputRedirected)
            {
                ResetTimer();
            }
        }


        public void Report(double value)
        {
            // Make sure value is in [0..1] range
            value = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(1, value));
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref currentProgress, value);
        }

        private void TimerHandler(object state)
        {
            lock (timer)
            {
                if (disposed) return;

                int progressBlockCount = (int)(currentProgress * blockCount);
                int percent = (int)(currentProgress * 100);
                string text = string.Format("[{0}{1}] {2,3}% {3}",
                    new string('#', progressBlockCount), new string('-', blockCount - progressBlockCount),
                    percent,
                    animation[animationIndex++ % animation.Length]);
                UpdateText(text);

                ResetTimer();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateText(string text)
        {
            // Get length of common portion
            int commonPrefixLength = 0;
            int commonLength = Math.Min(currentText.Length, text.Length);
            while (commonPrefixLength < commonLength && text[commonPrefixLength] == currentText[commonPrefixLength])
            {
                commonPrefixLength++;
            }

            // Backtrack to the first differing character
            StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            outputBuilder.Append('\b', currentText.Length - commonPrefixLength);

            // Output new suffix
            outputBuilder.Append(text.Substring(commonPrefixLength));

            // If the new text is shorter than the old one: delete overlapping characters
            int overlapCount = currentText.Length - text.Length;
            if (overlapCount > 0)
            {
                outputBuilder.Append(' ', overlapCount);
                outputBuilder.Append('\b', overlapCount);
            }

            Console.Write(outputBuilder);
            currentText = text;
        }

        private void ResetTimer()
        {
            timer.Change(animationInterval, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            lock (timer)
            {
                disposed = true;
                UpdateText(string.Empty);
            }
        }

    }
```